# Not able to login to sitefinity backend when restoring a copy of its database on a local computer

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-5, sitefinity-8, sitefinity-feather

I have recently started learning Sitefinity and done its setup and trying to login into Sitefinity backend by restoring a copy of an its existing database on my local system but my user is not present in that database so how can I login into the Sitefinity backend?
Is there any default credential present for login?
Is there any way to skip that login part or remove that login page?

Answer (score 1):

No, the default admin is created on setup.

Open the database and check out the users table. You can change the password format column to 0 (should be 1) then just set the password to anything you want right in the database.

... obviously don't set a plain text password for the admin user on a live database though

Answer (score 0):

@Steve is right. Here is a script that you can run against the DB:

```
update sf_users
set password_format = 0, -- clear text
salt = null,
passwd = 'veryStrongPa55' -- put whatever pass you like here
where user_name = 'xxx' -- change this
```

Then you may need to restart the application and should be able to login with that username.